# Обновить поле в таблице после добавления в нее записи используя триггер

Tags: oracle, plsql, триггер

Есть таблица документов, в ней есть поле `DOC_TYPE`

Нужно заполнять это поле в триггере после каждого добавления записи в таблицу.

Пробовал сделать так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DOCUMENTS_TRG
AFTER INSERT
ON DOCUMENTS
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    UPDATE DOCUMENTS 
    SET DOC_TYPE = (SUBSTR(LOWER(CAST(DOC_NAME AS VARCHAR2(512))),- INSTR(REVERSE(LOWER(CAST(DOC_NAME AS VARCHAR2(512)))), '.'))) 
    WHERE ID = :new.ID
END;
/
```

А еще так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DOCUMENTS_TRG
AFTER INSERT
ON DOCUMENTS
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF :new.DOC_TYPE IS NULL THEN
          :new.DOC_TYPE:= (SUBSTR(LOWER(:new.DOC_NAME),- INSTR(REVERSE(LOWER(:new.DOC_NAME)), '.')));         
    END IF;
END;
/
```

в первом случае я получал ошибку:

```
ORA-54017: UPDATE operation disallowed on virtual columns
ORA-06512: at "DOCUMENTS_TRG", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DOCUMENTS_TRG'
```

Во втором случае:

```
[Error] PLS-00201 (9: 68): PLS-00201: identifier 'REVERSE' must be declared
```

Как правильно апдейтить поле в таблице в моем случае?

Comment: На счет reverse не ясно что ему не нравится, но изменять поле надо как во втором варианте, только триггер должен быть `BEFORE`, а не `AFTER`

Comment: И кстати не ясно зачем вы пытаетесь менять виртуальную колонку. Если у вас Oracle 11 и виртуальные колонки есть - то  они должны вычисляться формулой объявленной при создании. Во всех остальных случаях колонка должна быть объявлена как обычная, а не виртуальная

Comment: основная база Oracle 11g, но нужно сделать поддержку Oracle 10g. Поставили задачу слелать это через триггеры.

Comment: тогда это как раз те самые "остальные случаи". делайте колонку обычной она будет работать в любых версиях или ведите 2 варианта кода для разных версий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал с помощью `Regex`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DOCUMENTS_TRG
AFTER INSERT
ON DOCUMENTS
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF :new.DOC_TYPE IS NULL THEN
          :new.DOC_TYPE:= LOWER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:new.DOC_NAME,'\.[^\.]+$'));         
    END IF;
END;
/
```